# jquery droppable on two divs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I am trying to create a app for manually creating a tennis lineup using jquery drag n drop.  There is a #Sideline div which has #Player divs.  There is a #Court div with quadrants (one per player)

I would like to limit the droppable divs to the court where they snap to to a quadrant (this is working) I would also like to add the abilty to move players back to the sideline (but limit dropping to the court or the sideline.

I have create a jsfiddle to demonstrate.

Thanks for your help!
Paul

**https://jsfiddle.net/pxg/2eq0vkt9/**

```js
$(".player").draggable();

$(".court_quarter").droppable({
  accept: ".player",
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    var droppable = $(this);
    var draggable = ui.draggable;
    // Move draggable into droppable
    draggable.appendTo(droppable);
    draggable.css({
      top: '0px',
      left: '0px'
    });
  }
});

$("#Lineup").droppable({
  accept: ".player",
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    var droppable = $(this);
    var draggable = ui.draggable;
    // Move draggable into droppable
    draggable.appendTo(droppable);
    draggable.css({
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.court_quarter {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #40A14C;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: white;
}

.court_name {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial Black;
}

.player {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-family: Arial Black;
  display:inline-block;
}

.male {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}

.female {
  background-color: deeppink;
  ##FF1493;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1 color=black>

  <tr>
    <th colspan=2>
      <div id="#Court1" class="court_name">COURT 1</div>
    </th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="GridDiv1" class="court_quarter"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="GridDiv2" class="court_quarter"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="GridDiv3" class="court_quarter"> </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="GridDiv4" class="court_quarter"> </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br>

<table border=1 color= black height=100 width = 100%>
<tr>
<td>
<div id="Lineup" style="text-align: left">
<div id="Player1" class="player male">
  <br>PAUL</div>
<div id="Player2" class="player male">
  <br>CHERYL</div>
<div id="Player3" class="player female">
  <br>SHANON</div>
<div id="Player4" class="player female">
  <br>DAYONG</div>
   
  </div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what's working and what's not and what you want to be able to do that it isn't doing now.

Comment: @jonmrich Thanks for your interest in helping.  I can drop in the court and it snaps to a quadrant.  But, I want to limit the draggable so that it can only be dropped on another quadrant, or back in the lineup.  Currenty, I can drop it anywhere.

Comment: In other words...you want it so that only one player can be in a single quadrant? That is, if there's another player in the quadrant already, then the quadrant is "locked" so you can't add more players. Correct?

Comment: @jonmrich - Thats correct.  But in addition, I would like to be able to move the drop the player back into the Lineup or to another quadrant.  But not to any other place.

Comment: This should help: https://jqueryui.com/droppable/#revert Also, check photo gallery example...